# How to statically declare letters without using charcode in HTML Canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have this [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/tomjerry25/p14rbd4e/3/)  which connects 4 points.

What I want is to have letters of [S,T,A,R] not continues letter. Once the user click draw it will draw another  points of  [S,T,A,R] with the new coordinates the user wants.

Sample snippet:

```
for(var i=0;i<connectors.length;i++){
    var c=connectors[i];
    var s=anchors[c.start];
    var e=anchors[c.end];
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(s.x,s.y);
    ctx.lineTo(e.x,e.y);
    ctx.stroke();
}  

//draw lines
if (anchors.length>0 && anchors.length%4>0){
   ctx.strokeStyle='gray';
   var al = anchors.length-1;
   var almod4 = al%4;
   if (almod4==1 || almod4==2){
   //draw extra line
       ctx.beginPath();
       ctx.moveTo(anchors[al-1].x,anchors[al-1].y);
       ctx.lineTo(mouseX,mouseY);
       ctx.stroke();
   }
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.moveTo(anchors[al].x,anchors[al].y);
   ctx.lineTo(mouseX,mouseY);
   ctx.stroke();
}
```

Comment: I"m not really sure what you mean by *" letters of [S,T,A,R] not continues letter"*. Also where an how does the user change the coordinates?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek. I think instead of A,B,C,D labels they want labels spelling S,T,A,R. And after the user clicks 4 times to spell STAR, the fifth click should restart S--- over again.   Shrug.

Comment: It means that the letter will be first 'S' then 'T' and so on. It will not redraw it will add new set of 4 points [S,T,A,R]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To only have it have the letters `[S,T,A,R]` you can have a letter array that holds those letters and have `addAnchor()` use the items from that array incremently (and doing `mod Array.length` to wrap around to the start again):

```
var letters = ["S", "T", "A", "R"];

function addAnchor(x,y){
    anchors.push({
        label:letters[nextLetter],
        x:x,
        y:y,
    });
    nextLetter = (nextLetter+1) % letters.length;
}
```

[**Fiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/p14rbd4e/5/)

Note you may want to reset the value for `nextLetter` when the canvas is cleared.

For only having one set you have have the same array, but instead remove the first element and only add a node when the array isn't empty:

```
function addAnchor(x,y){
    if(letters.length)
    {
        anchors.push({
            label:letters[0],
            x:x,
            y:y,
        });
        letters.shift();    
    } 
}
```

Then you can add the letters back when the draw button is clicked (*you can either set the array like so or append the four letters on the array depending on what you wish to do*):

```
 $("#draw").click(function(){
    letters = ["S", "T", "A", "R"];
 });
```

[**Fiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/p14rbd4e/6/)